# Using `case` to handle script arguments

Tags: bash, shell

Can I use the `case` statement to handle arguments? So, using -restart I'd like execute "-umount" and "-mount"

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
-mount
mount /ip/share1 /local/share1
;;
-umount
umount /ip/share1
;;
-restart
# echo TODO
;;
*)
[...]
esac
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks to me like that should work, other than the syntactical quibble of missing `)`s. I tested this and it behaves correctly..

```
#/bin/bash
case "$1" in
  "-mount")
    mount /path/to/device /path/to/mountpoint
    ;;
  "-unmount")
    umount /path/to/mountpoint
    ;;
  "-remount")
    "$0" -unmount
    "$0" -mount
    ;;
  *)
    echo "You have failed to specify what to do correctly."
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Not good solution: inside "-remount" I don't want rewrite same code of "-mount" and "-umount" (the code above is only an example - real code is more than long). Thanks for help! :-)

Comment: I have altered the answer to not have duplicated code, but rather to recurse.

Comment: Can you tell me about $0? I didn't known it. Thanks!

Comment: `$0` is the zeroth paramater to a script or function; in this case, the invocation of the script itself.  If I invoke a script with `./script foo bar`; `$0` is "`./script`", `$1` is "`foo`", and `$2` is "`bar`".

Comment: I'm pleased to be able to assist!

Comment: Isn't `-remount` going to recurse indefinitely?

Comment: in remount you want to: `shift ;  $0 -unmount "$@" ; $0 -mount "$@" ;;` (... so you don t loop on -remount, and you also pass along any remaining parameters)

Comment: Oh, of course.  It should call `-unmount` and then `-mount`, *not* `-remount`.  That fixes that problem.

Comment: Valid points all.  I suppose I was concentrating more on the question of using `case..esac` to handle arguments at all.  I too would be more inclined to use the functional route if I were authoring such a script.

Comment: @DopeGhoti - oh, an addendum to above - it *also* drops shell options. So I guess you also need... `shift; exec "$0" "-$-" -- -[u]mount "$@"`. Dang.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
unset u
mnt() { ${u+u}mount /ip/share1 ${u-"/local/share1"}; }
case "$1"   in
(-mount)            :;; 
(-umount)  u=        ;;
(-restart) u= mnt    ;;
(*)               ! :;;
esac && mnt
```

You could use a function as ^above^.